# Can Mathematica’s automated theorem prover and assistant work with the axioms of real (or complex) numbers?

Tags: theorem-proving

[axioms of real numbers](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ehart/m524/realprop.pdf)

The question pretty much says it all. If I can make Mathematica do simple limit proofs that would be a good start.

Of course what I’d really like to do is turn this loose on the Riemann hypothesis…

Comment: P13 is too hard for current CASes. I think the implementation of the reals as an axiomatic theory in Mathematica is a matter of the far future.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [ProofAssistants.SE](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/).